# Sort Pivoted Column Name of Type Date in Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I pivoted a year-mon column using a quantity for the value, but the columns show up out of order. Is there a way to get these to reorder in the correct order without having to manually reorder them every time? The order I would like is: 2017-November, 2017-December, 2018-January.

[image]

Here is the Power M Code:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(#"Merge With New Data Source",{"Ship to Name", "Ship to Postal Code"},#"Ship to Address",{"Name", "Post_Code"},"Ship to Address",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded Ship to Address" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Ship to Address", {"City", "County"}, {"Ship to Address.City", "Ship to Address.County"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Ship to Address",{{"Ship to Address.City", "Ship to City"}, {"Ship to Address.County", "Ship to State"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Ship to Name", "Ship to City", "Ship to State", "Ship to Postal Code", "Bill to Name", "Item No", "Item Description", "2018-January", "2017-November", "2017-December"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Ship to Postal Code"})
in 
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Can you provide the **Power M Code**? you can get it in Home tab, Advanced Editor

Comment: I added the code above ^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sort function `Table.Sort(...),{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}})`

Your last line will be:

```
#"Removed Columns" = Table.Sort(Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Ship to Postal Code"})),{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}})
```

The problem is, it will organize the fields like `[2017-Dec...], [2017-Nov...], [2018-Jan...]` because they are not "date type".

I add some lines to fix that concatenating Year-MonthNum-MonthName: `[2017-11-Nov], [2017-12-Dec], [2018-1-Jan]`.

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(#"Merge With New Data Source",{"Ship to Name", "Ship to Postal Code"},#"Ship to Address",{"Name", "Post_Code"},"Ship to Address",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded Ship to Address" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Ship to Address", {"City", "County"}, {"Ship to Address.City", "Ship to Address.County"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Ship to Address",{{"Ship to Address.City", "Ship to City"}, {"Ship to Address.County", "Ship to State"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Ship to Name", "Ship to City", "Ship to State", "Ship to Postal Code", "Bill to Name", "Item No", "Item Description", "2018-January", "2017-November", "2017-December"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Ship to Postal Code"}),

    //Transform each date field as registers
    UnpivotedDatesFields = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"Item Description", "Item No", "Bill to Name", "Ship to State", "Ship to City", "Ship to Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    // Transform new field Attribute as Date Type
    FormatDate = Table.TransformColumnTypes(UnpivotedDatesFields,{{"Attribute", type date}}),
    //Extract Year From Attribute
    Year = Table.AddColumn(FormatDate, "Year", each Date.Year([Attribute]), Int64.Type),
    //Extract Month Number From Attribute
    Month = Table.AddColumn(Year, "Month", each Date.Month([Attribute]), Int64.Type),
    //Extract Month Name from Attribute and returns the first three characters
    MonthName = Table.AddColumn(Month, "Month Name", each Text.Start(Date.MonthName([Attribute]),3), type text),
    //Concatenate Year, Month number, and Month Name using "-" as delimiter and sort in order A-Z
    MergedColumns = Table.Sort(Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(MonthName, {{"Year", type text}, {"Month", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Year", "Month", "Month Name"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.None),"Dates"),{{"Dates", Order.Ascending}}),
    //Remove Attribute
    RemovedOldDate = Table.RemoveColumns(MergedColumns,{"Attribute"}),
    //Return Date registers as fields again
    PivotedColumn = Table.Pivot(RemovedOldDate, List.Distinct(RemovedOldDate[Dates]), "Dates", "Value", List.Sum)
in
    PivotedColumn
```

[image]

Let me know if this worked for you!

Comment: This is great! I stripped out the month name to reduce redundancy and it works perfectly. Thanks for the help!